# Scala - Two functions sharing the second parameter list

Tags: scala, currying

I am new in Scala and I just came across a situation that I would like someone could explain me.

When watching a Martin Odersky's course I found the following script he uses to explain functions which return a function

```
val tolerance = 0.0001 

def isCloseEnough(x : Double, y : Double) = abs((x - y)/ x) / x < tolerance  

def fixedPoint(f : Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double) = {
    def iterate(guess: Double): Double = {
        val next = f(guess)
        if(isCloseEnough(guess,next))next
        else iterate(next)
    }
        iterate(firstGuess)
  }                                              

fixedPoint(x => 1 + x/2)(1)    

def averageDamp(f: Double => Double)(x: Double) =  (x + f(x))/2

def sqrt(x : Double) = fixedPoint(averageDamp(y => x/y))(1)


sqrt(2)
```

I understand perfectly how the scrip works, but I didn't expect this line:

**fixedPoint(averageDamp(y => x/y))(1)**

I know that thanks to Currying, Scala let us write functions with several parameter list. So the call to *fixedPoint* passing as parameter the result of *avergaDamp* and (1) is clear for me.

What I don't understand is how *averageDamp* uses the second parameter list of *fixedPoint* when it itself is inside the first parameter list. I though that would be a different scope, so I was expecting something like:

fixedPoint(**averageDamp(y => x/y)(1)**)(1)

What is the property of Scala which allow us to implement the currying in this way? Is something similar to an implicit applied to a parameter list?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how multiple parameter lists work: `averageDamp(y => x/y)` is equivalent to `z => averageDamp(y => x/y)(z)` and so its type is `Double => Double`.

If you wrote `fixedPoint(averageDamp(y => x/y)(1))(1)` as you expect, it would have a type mismatch because `averageDamp(y => x/y)(1)` has type `Double` and `fixedPoint` needs `Double => Double`.

Implicits aren't relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

This line works because in the following expression:

```
fixedPoint(averageDamp(y => x/y))(1)
```

function "averageDamp(y => x/y)" is "passed by name" i.e. it will not be evaluated while passing to function "fixedPoint" but will be evaluated when it is called from inside "fixedPoint".

value "(1)" is just pass to argument "firstGuess" of "fixedPoint" which will be supplied to parameter "guess" inside the function definition in following expression:

```
val next = f(guess)
```